# MacOS equivalent for /etc/environ

Tags: macos, network, proxy

I am at a new institute and to use the Wi-Fi they had to configure some proxies settings on my personal laptop. Now I cant access the internet from my home.

A friend who has a Linux laptop said he just has to comment out the settings in his `/etc/environ/` file at home.

Is there an equivalent file where I would find the proxy settings?

Answer (score 2):

There is a similar file in macOS (*/Library/Preferences/SystemConfiguration/preferences.plist*), but it's not intended to edit the file manually.

Instead the prefpane System Preferences > Network is used to set-up several "locations". A "location" provides a custom network set-up including activated or deactivated network interfaces or IP and proxy settings. The default location is "Automatic".

An example set-up is shown here:

[image: Network Preferences]

In the left pane the interfaces are listed. By choosing an interface its configuration is shown in the right pane.

By hitting the <kbd>Advanced</kbd> button you are redirected to some special settings including the proxy settings.

[image]

By hitting the drop-down "Locations" and the gear you can edit the name or duplicate a locations profile:

[image]

In your case do the following:

Rename the "Automatic" profile to "Lab" (or "Work"/"Institute") hit <kbd>Done</kbd> and hit <kbd>Apply</kbd>.

Then duplicate the Lab profile, rename the copy to "Home" and hit <kbd>Done</kbd>.

Choose the profile "Home" in the Location drop-down and hit <kbd>Apply</kbd>. Configure the IP-settings for your home network: DHCP or manually.
Click the "Advanced..." button > Proxy and deselect all proxy settings - if any exist, hit <kbd>OK</kbd> and hit <kbd>Apply</kbd>.

Now at work/university choose the "Lab" profile and at home the "Home" profile in the Apple menu > Locations.